# Calculating the finish date and time taking into account only business working hours

Tags: c#, scheduler

I wrote a basic, configurable class that allows us to calculate the end date of a scheduled task it's take into account for business working days and hours, weekends and publics holidays.

It is possible for us to define the public holidays or  modify  working hours independently of the days, we can set a diffrent working times for each days, according to the tests I've done so far, the class works as expected.

But I know that there are more elegant way to achieve the same goal, I share with you my code, for those who can help to improve it and benefit those who need a similar function.

[Project link on GitHub](https://github.com/aityahiaidir/ScheduleCalculator/blob/main/ScheduleCalculator.cs)

```
using System.Globalization;

namespace akerdis.Scheduler

{
    public class WorkTime

    {
        public TimeSpan FromTime { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan ToTime { get; set; }



        public WorkTime(TimeSpan from, TimeSpan to)

        {
            FromTime = from;
            ToTime = to;
        }



        public bool isWorkTime(TimeSpan time)

        {
            TimeSpan timeCore = default(TimeSpan).Add(time);
            return (timeCore >= FromTime) && (timeCore <= ToTime);

        }



    }

    public class WorkDay

    {

        public DayOfWeek Day { get; set; }
        public bool isNotWorkDay { get; set; } = false;
        public IList<WorkTime>? WorkTimes { get; set; }

        public WorkDay(DayOfWeek day, bool notWorkDay = false)

        {

            Day = day;

            isNotWorkDay = notWorkDay;

            if (notWorkDay == false)

            {
                WorkTimes = new List<WorkTime>

                {
                    new WorkTime(new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(12, 0, 0)),
                    new WorkTime(new TimeSpan(13, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(16, 0, 0))
                };

            }



        }

        public bool isWorkingDay { get { return !isNotWorkDay; } }


    }
    public class Holiday

    {
        public DateTime HolidayDate { get; set; }
        public string? HolidayName { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfDays { get; set; } = 1;


        public Holiday(DateTime date)
        {
            this.HolidayDate = date;
        }

        public Holiday(DateTime date, string name)
        {
            this.HolidayDate = date;
            this.HolidayName = name;
        }


        public Holiday(DateTime date, string name, int number)

        {
            this.HolidayDate = date;
            this.HolidayName = name;
            this.NumberOfDays = number;
        }


    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Class <c>ScheduleCalculator</c> utility class that allows us calculating the finish date and time 
    /// of a working task.
    /// /// <para>
    /// the calculation is based on the start date and  duration and takes into account
    /// of public holidays, business working days 
    /// </para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <author>
    /// AIT YAHIA Idir
    /// </author>
    /// <date>
    /// 02/27/2023
    /// </date>
    public class ScheduleCalculator

    {

        protected Dictionary<DayOfWeek, WorkDay> WorkDayOfWeeks = new Dictionary<DayOfWeek, WorkDay>()

        {
            { DayOfWeek.Sunday, new WorkDay(DayOfWeek.Sunday) },
            { DayOfWeek.Monday, new WorkDay(DayOfWeek.Monday) },
            { DayOfWeek.Tuesday, new WorkDay(DayOfWeek.Tuesday) },
            { DayOfWeek.Wednesday, new WorkDay(DayOfWeek.Wednesday)},
            { DayOfWeek.Thursday, new WorkDay(DayOfWeek.Thursday) },
            { DayOfWeek.Friday, new WorkDay(DayOfWeek.Friday,true) },
            { DayOfWeek.Saturday, new WorkDay(DayOfWeek.Saturday,true) },
         };



        public Holiday[] Holidays { get; set; } = { new Holiday(new(2023, 1, 1), "New year"), new Holiday(new DateTime(2023, 2, 26), "Jour de test", 2) };

        public bool isHoliday(DateTime date)
        {
            return Array.Exists(Holidays, holiday =>
            {
                if ((date >= holiday.HolidayDate) && (date <= holiday.HolidayDate.AddDays(holiday.NumberOfDays - 1)))
                { return true; }
                return false;
            });
        }

        public static bool IsValidTimeFormat(string input)
        {
            TimeSpan dummyOutput;
            return TimeSpan.TryParse(input, out dummyOutput);
        }

        public static bool IsValidDateTimeFormat(string input)
        {
            DateTime dummyOutput;
            return DateTime.TryParse(input, out dummyOutput);
        }

        public DateTime CalcFinishDate(string startDate, string duration)

        {


            DateTime _startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(startDate, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm",
                                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            TimeSpan _duration = default(TimeSpan).Add(TimeSpan.ParseExact(duration, "hh\\:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); ;
            return CalcFinishDate(_startDate, _duration);
        }
        public DateTime CalcFinishDate(DateTime startDate, TimeSpan duration)

        {
            if (duration == TimeSpan.Zero) { return startDate; }



            TimeSpan remainingDuration = duration;
            DateTime start_date = startDate;
            DateTime end_date = startDate + remainingDuration;
            DateTime nextDay = startDate.Date;
            TimeSpan timeToReduce = TimeSpan.Zero;



            while (remainingDuration > TimeSpan.Zero)

            {
                DayOfWeek day = nextDay.DayOfWeek;
                WorkDay wd = WorkDayOfWeeks[day];

                if ((wd.isWorkingDay) && (!isHoliday(nextDay)))

                {

                    foreach (WorkTime wt in wd.WorkTimes)

                    {
                        if (remainingDuration > TimeSpan.Zero)
                        {
                            DateTime period_start_date = nextDay.Date.Add(wt.FromTime);
                            DateTime period_end_date = nextDay.Date.Add(wt.ToTime);

                            if (start_date <= period_start_date)
                            {

                                start_date = period_start_date;
                                end_date = start_date.Add(remainingDuration);

                                if (end_date < period_start_date)
                                {
                                    timeToReduce = TimeSpan.Zero;
                                }
                                else
                                if ((end_date >= period_start_date) && (end_date < period_end_date))
                                {
                                    timeToReduce = end_date.Subtract(period_start_date);

                                }
                                else
                                if (end_date > period_end_date)
                                {
                                    end_date = period_end_date;
                                    timeToReduce = end_date.Subtract(start_date);

                                }
                            }

                            else if (start_date > period_start_date)
                            {
                                if (start_date > period_end_date)
                                {
                                    timeToReduce = TimeSpan.Zero;
                                }
                                else
                                    if ((start_date < end_date) && (end_date > period_end_date))
                                {
                                    end_date = period_end_date;
                                    timeToReduce = end_date.Subtract(start_date);

                                }
                                else if (end_date < period_end_date)
                                {
                                    timeToReduce = end_date.Subtract(start_date);

                                }
                            }


                            remainingDuration = remainingDuration.Subtract(timeToReduce);

                        }
                    }
                }

                nextDay = nextDay.AddDays(1);

            }


            return end_date;

        }


    }

}
```

Example of use

```
DateTime? date = scheduler.CalcFinishDate(new DateTime(2023, 02, 23, 16, 00, 00), new TimeSpan(08, 15, 0));
```

or

```
DateTime? date = scheduler.CalcFinishDate("27/02/2023 09:36","05:30");
```

Comment: StackOverflow is for practical problems in computer programming and since your code works it isn't a "problem" as such. For code improvements you should post on https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: What happens, in your code, if someone has a night-shift? They start at, say, 22:00 and finish at 07:00?

Comment: Why do you do `default(TimeSpan).Add(time)` and not just use `time` directly?

Comment: You should avoid `bool notWorkDay = false` (it's confusing) and use `enum DayType { Working, Nonworking }` instead. A `bool` makes a good return type and local variables, but not parameters. `var result = MyMethod(true, false, false, true)` is just awful.

Comment: I use default TimeStamp to bé sure tha i get only the Time

Comment: @Enigmativity if de dont définie a Working Times in this interval, thé task in thé n'est business working shift

Comment: `default(TimeSpan).Add(time)` is identical to `time`. It doesn't change the value at all.

Comment: Are you saying the working times during the day are fixed? It'll never span midnight?

Comment: Which is easier to read (1) `if (notWorkDay == false)` or (2) `if (dayType == DayType.Workday)`?

Comment: No working Time is n'ont fixed but i just define a default values when instantiating  the class, i will surcharge thé constructor and adding some methods to settings working days and times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my version of your code:

```
public class WorkTime
{
    public TimeSpan FromTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan ToTime { get; set; }

    public WorkTime(TimeSpan from, TimeSpan to)
    {
        FromTime = from;
        ToTime = to;
    }
}

public class WorkDay : IEnumerable<(DateTime start, DateTime end)>
{
    public DateOnly Date { get; private set; }
    public IList<WorkTime> WorkTimes { get; private set; } = new List<WorkTime>();

    public WorkDay(DateOnly date, DayType dayType = DayType.Workday)
    {
        this.Date = date;
        if (dayType == DayType.Workday)
        {
            this.WorkTimes.Add(new WorkTime(new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(12, 0, 0)));
            this.WorkTimes.Add(new WorkTime(new TimeSpan(13, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(16, 0, 0)));
        }
    }

    public bool IsWorkingDay => this.WorkTimes.Any();

    public IEnumerator<(DateTime start, DateTime end)> GetEnumerator() =>
        this
            .WorkTimes
            .Select(x => (this.Date.ToDateTime(x.FromTime), this.Date.ToDateTime(x.ToTime)))
            .GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => this.GetEnumerator();
}

public class Holiday
{
    public DateOnly Date { get; private set; }
    public string? Name { get; private set; }
    public int Days { get; private set; }

    public Holiday(DateOnly date) : this(date, "Unnamed") { }

    public Holiday(DateOnly date, string name) : this(date, name, 1) { }

    public Holiday(DateOnly date, string name, int days)
    {
        this.Date = date;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Days = days;
    }
}

public class ScheduleCalculator
{
    private Holiday[] Holidays { get; set; } = { new Holiday(new(2023, 1, 1), "New year"), new Holiday(new(2023, 2, 26), "Jour de test", 2) };

    private bool IsHoliday(DateOnly date) =>
        date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday
        || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday
        || this.Holidays.Where(x => date >= x.Date   && date < x.Date.AddDays(x.Days)).Any();
    
    private IEnumerable<WorkDay> WorkDayGenerator(DateOnly startDate)
    {
        DateOnly date = startDate;
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WorkDay(date, this.IsHoliday(date) ? DayType.Nonworkday : DayType.Workday);
            date = date.AddDays(1);
        }
    }
    
    public DateTime CalcFinishDateTime(DateTime startDateTime, TimeSpan duration)
    {
        if (duration == TimeSpan.Zero) return startDateTime;
        DateTime currentDateTime = startDateTime;
        foreach (WorkDay workDay in WorkDayGenerator(currentDateTime.ToDateOnly()))
        {
            foreach ((DateTime workStartDateTime, DateTime workEndDateTime) in workDay)
            {
                if (currentDateTime < workStartDateTime)
                {
                    currentDateTime = workStartDateTime;
                }
                if (currentDateTime < workEndDateTime)
                {
                    TimeSpan remaining = workEndDateTime - currentDateTime;
                    if (duration < remaining)
                    {
                        return currentDateTime.Add(duration);
                    }
                    if (duration == remaining)
                    {
                        return workEndDateTime;
                    }
                    duration -= remaining;
                }
            }
        }
        //Code can never get here as WorkDayGenerator is infinite
        return default(DateTime);
    }
}

public enum DayType { Workday, Nonworkday, }

public static class DateEx
{
    public static DateOnly ToDateOnly(this DateTime dateTime) => new DateOnly(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, dateTime.Day);

    public static DateTime ToDateTime(this DateOnly dateOnly) => new DateTime(dateOnly.Year, dateOnly.Month, dateOnly.Day);
    
    public static DateTime ToDateTime(this DateOnly dateOnly, TimeSpan timeSpan) => dateOnly.ToDateTime().Add(timeSpan);

    public static TimeSpan? TryParseTimeFormat(this string input) => TimeSpan.TryParseExact(input, "hh\\:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out TimeSpan timeSpan) ? timeSpan : null;

    public static DateTime? TryParseDateTimeFormat(string input) => DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dateTime) ? dateTime : null;
}
```

Comment: Your code is more elegant, and I have just learned new programming techniques, I will test it thoroughly, however there is an error, The code fail to compile, with error IList<WorkTime>does not contain a definition for 'IsEmpty' and no accessible extension method 'IsEmpty'

Comment: Add `using System.Linq;` to the start of your code.

Comment: Linq is already in the using  statement, i use .Net Core 6.0

Comment: @AitYahiaIdir - Sorry, that was in an extension library I use. I updated it with `.Any()` instead.

Comment: the result is not that expect for following example `DateTime date = scheduler.CalcFinishDateTime(new(2023, 02, 23, 15, 0, 0), new(8, 15, 0));` it's should be 28/02/2023 a 08:15

Comment: after debugging i find the problem, you have permuted operand in `this.Holidays.Where(x => x.Date >= date && date < x.Date.AddDays(x.Days)).Any();` it's should be `date>=x.Date`, now it's work as expected, i will a adopt your solution in my project, thank's for helping.